# Having an issue, i want to be able to press the "edit" button on the GUI and which will open up a new seperate window that can allow me to change valu

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Having an issue, i want to be able to press the "edit" button on the GUI and which will open up a new seperate window that can allow me to change values. But I have having some trouble with getting the new window to work and assigning it to the different edit buttons. Thanks

````
#Edit Function
def create_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text="Create new window", command=create_window)
b.pack()
#Tkinter Window    
root = Tk()
#Labels
lblTitle = Label(text="Chelsea FC Player Statistics",font=('bold', 15), fg="blue",).grid(row=0, column=1)
#Player Names Labels
lblPlayerNames = Label(text="Player Names",font=('bold')).grid(columnspan=1,row=1, column=1)
lblDKName = Label(text="Daniel Keelagher").grid(columnspan=1,row=2, column=1)
lblJKName = Label(text="Joseph Keelagher").grid(columnspan=1,row=3, column=1)
lblBMName = Label(text="Benjamin Miller").grid(columnspan=1,row=4, column=1)
lblJTName = Label(text="Jordan Terlato").grid(columnspan=1,row=5, column=1)
#Matches Played Labels
lblMatchesPlayed = Label(text="Matches Played",font=('bold')).grid(columnspan=1,row=1, column=2)
lblDKMatches = Label(text="10").grid(columnspan=1,row=2, column=2)
lblJKMatches = Label(text="9").grid(columnspan=1,row=3, column=2)
lblBMMatches = Label(text="9").grid(columnspan=1,row=4, column=2)
lblJTMatches = Label(text="8").grid(columnspan=1,row=5, column=2)
#Goals Labels
lblGoals = Label(text="Goals",font=('bold')).grid(row=1, column=3)
lblDKGoals = Label(text="4").grid(columnspan=1,row=2, column=3)
lblJKGoals = Label(text="2").grid(columnspan=1,row=3, column=3)
lblBMGoals = Label(text="0").grid(columnspan=1,row=4, column=3)
lblJTGoals = Label(text="1").grid(columnspan=1,row=5, column=3)
#Assists Labels
lblAssists = Label(text="Assists",font=('bold')).grid(columnspan=1,row=1, column=4)
lblDKAssists = Label(text="4").grid(columnspan=1,row=2, column=4)
lblJKAssists = Label(text="2").grid(columnspan=1,row=3, column=4)
lblBMAssists = Label(text="0").grid(columnspan=1,row=4, column=4)
lblJTAssists = Label(text="1").grid(columnspan=1,row=5, column=4)
#YellowCards Labels
lblYellowCards = Label(text="YC",font=('bold')).grid(columnspan=1,row=1, column=5)
lblDKYellowCards = Label(text="0").grid(columnspan=1,row=2, column=5)
lblJKYellowCards = Label(text="1").grid(columnspan=1,row=3, column=5)
lblBMYellowCards = Label(text="1").grid(columnspan=1,row=4, column=5)
lblJTYellowCards = Label(text="3").grid(columnspan=1,row=5, column=5)
#RedCards Labels
lblYellowCards = Label(text="RC",font=('bold')).grid(columnspan=1,row=1, column=6)
lblDKRedCards = Label(text="0").grid(columnspan=1,row=2, column=6)
lblJKRedCards = Label(text="0").grid(columnspan=1,row=3, column=6)
lblBMRedCards = Label(text="0").grid(columnspan=1,row=4, column=6)
lblJTRedCards = Label(text="1").grid(columnspan=1,row=5, column=6)


#Buttons
btnDKEdit = Button(root, text="Edit",).grid(columnspan=1,row=2, column=7)
btnJKEdit = Button(root, text="Edit", ).grid(columnspan=1,row=3, column=7)
btnBMEdit = Button(root, text="Edit", ).grid(columnspan=1,row=4,column=7)
btbJTEdit = Button(root, text="Edit",).grid(columnspan=1,row=5, column=7)```
````

Comment: Why do you have `root = tk.Tk()` inside the `create_window` function? `window = tk.Toplevel(root)` creates the new window. Why use `Tk()` just after it?

Comment: i just copyed and paste it off somewhere ? sorry what do i do to make the "Edit" button open a new window? @TheLizzard

Comment: Try removing the `root = tk.Tk()`. Also please don't just copy/paste code if you don't know how it works. Also have you looked at tkinter tutorials?

Comment: I suggest using dictionaries to store information rather than individual labels

Comment: also those labels have to have a master; a place where they are put

Answer (score 0):

I think I already answered this question but anyways here You go (You posted the same question twice?):

Here is my solution (pretty long but I will try to explain most of the parts as best as I can (explanation below) however in this case there won't be a new window and also this is more of an example of how that might be done just to give You an idea.):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Frame, Label, StringVar
from tkinter.ttk import Separator
from functools import partial


stored_data = {'Lionel Notmessi': {'Games Played': 340, 'Goals': 102, 'Assists': 223}, 'Firstname Lastname': {'Games Played': 279, 'Goals': 84, 'Assists': 56}}


class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.players_frame = Frame(self)
        self.players_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.data_value_list = []

        for index, player in enumerate(list(stored_data)):
            player_frame = Frame(self.players_frame)
            player_frame.pack(side='left')
            Label(player_frame, text=player, height=2, width=30, anchor='n', font='default 11 bold').pack(side='top', pady=10)

            var = StringVar()
            self.data_value_list.append(var)

            Label(player_frame, textvariable=self.data_value_list[index], height=8, width=30).pack(side='top', pady=10)

            Button(player_frame, text='Edit', command=partial(self.select, player)).pack(side='bottom', pady=10, fill='x', expand=True)

        self.refresh_data()

    def select(self, key):
        self.players_frame.pack_forget()
        player_edit_frame = EditData(self, stored_data, key)
        player_edit_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    def refresh_data(self):
        for var, player in zip(self.data_value_list, list(stored_data)):
            data = ''
            for name, value in stored_data[player].items():
                data += f'{name}: {value}\n\n'
            var.set(data)


class EditData(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data, key):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.data = data
        self.key = key

        self.total_width = len(list(data[key].keys()))

        name = Label(self, text=key, anchor='n', height=3)
        name.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=self.total_width, sticky='nsew', pady=10)

        self.value_list = []
        index = 0
        for key, value in data[self.key].items():
            item_frame = Frame(self)
            item_frame.grid(row=1, column=index, sticky='nsew', padx=5)
            for i in range(3):
                item_frame.columnconfigure(i, minsize=50)

            var = StringVar()
            var.set(value)
            self.value_list.append(var)

            Label(item_frame, text=key).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')

            minus = Button(item_frame, text='-', command=partial(self.change, self.value_list[index], '-', key))
            minus.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

            value_label = Label(item_frame, textvariable=self.value_list[index])
            value_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')

            plus = Button(item_frame, text='+', command=partial(self.change, self.value_list[index], '+', key))
            plus.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='nsew')

            index += 1

        Separator(self, orient='horizontal').grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=self.total_width, sticky='nsew', pady=5)

        Button(self, text='Done', command=self.done).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=self.total_width, sticky='nsew')

    def change(self, var, operator, key):
        current = var.get()
        if operator == '-':
            total = int(current) - 1
            var.set(str(total))
            self.data[self.key][key] = total
        if operator == '+':
            total = int(current) + 1
            var.set(str(total))
            self.data[self.key][key] = total

    def done(self):
        self.parent.refresh_data()
        self.parent.players_frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
        self.destroy()


root = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

So the first thing is to import all the necessary modules that will be used.

Next I set a variable `stored_data` to a dictionary which will be the main data storage place where all the data about players will be stored.

Then I created a class called `MainWindow` which inherits from `Tk` which is the main window of tkinter so that way it is possible to get the `Tk()` functionality for example the `.mainloop()` method.

In the `MainWindow` constructor method (what will get called on initiating) first I set the window to unresizable in both x and y directions so to not cause problems with widgets not being visible.

Then I created a frame to organize where all the player stuff will be displayed and also created another list for storing StringVar values so that it is easy to update the current data labels (the ones that are seen when launching the program).

Then for each key in the dictionary I created a frame to again organize displayed widgets. Then in the frame I packed all the stuff that is related, I put in the player name, their stats and the edit button (since I was focusing only on that functionality). Also appended a StringVar to list for each of the players. Those StringVar set the value of the label that will display the stats. And the StringVar is accessed by index.

Then I called `self.refresh_data()` which basically sets a value for each StringVar in the list to the according dictionary values. Basically displays stats.

Then there is also the `select()` method defined (it is called by a button) which initiates `EditData` and then puts it on the screen after removing the `self.players_frame` from the geometry manager so that it is no more visible and only the edit frame is visible.

The `EditData` class. Upon being initiated it takes the argument given to it and sets them as class attributes for easier access across the class.

Then total width is measured to calculate the columnspan of the grid and it is done by mesuring the length of list created by `stored_data` keys so basically the length is the amount of players.

Then the name is put on screen.

Again is created another `self.value_list` for storing StringVar and an index is set to 0 (since I couldn't figure out how to implement it (easy enough) in the for loop (using `enumerate()`)). and the index is increased every iteration.

Then Labels and button are created and gridded to the `item_frame` which is inside the class which inherits from Frame so basically the class is a bigger Frame and inside it the program creates smaller frames for data changing and layout organization purposes. Then inside the `item_frame` each column is set to minsize=50 so that they are the same size since none of the data takes up that much space anyways.

Then again a StringVar is set and appended to the list to access it later.

The whole

```
  name 
- data +
```

layout is created and buttons are set to the method `change()` and given the arguments (the `partial()` sets those function to always execute with the same given variables so that it is possible to create buttons in a loop easily). When change is called it get the current value of that data part and then depending on whether it is a "-" or "+" it adds or subtracts from the current value and sets it as the new value and also changes the value in the dictionary so that next time this frames is show it shows the new data and so that the stats on the "front page" show the updated data.

There is also the "Done" button which when pressed calls the `done()` method which then calls parent (which is `MainWindow`) method `refresh_data()` to display the new data, then it packs back that frame that was removed before when calling this class and then destroys itself.

And then we just initiate `MainWindow`:

```
root = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

And that is it.

Obviously some design improvements can be done.
Also if You wanted to save data so that the changed data shows every time You start You can write the data to a file before closing the window.

If You have questions just ask them.

About that file saving:

You can add this (`MainWindow` class):

```
self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda: self.save(stored_data))
```

to the `__init__` method to execute the function given when closing the window

also add this:

```
with open('stored_data.json') as file:
    stored_data = json.load(file)
```

at the start of You file but make sure that You have that file in Your directory also You have to:

```
import json
```

and then define the `save()` method (in the `MainWindow` class) that is called when closing the window:

```
def save(self, data):
        with open('stored_data.json', 'w') as file_:
            json.dump(data, file_, indent=2)
        self.destroy()
```

so that it writes the updated data to that file and remember to destroy the window afterwards otherwise it won't close.

Now You are able to load data when running the program and if You make changes they will be saved to the file to access them next time You run the program.

Also if You run out of space on the screen to display all players You can use Scrollbar to make it scrollable.

Again if You have questions ask them.

Comment: I can't believe I am about to say this, but IMO too much explanation can bloat your answer unnecessarily, always try to keep it minimal.

Comment: @CoolCloud well I was trying to explain every detail because I assumed the OP didn't know anything about this, the basics maybe but the OP should actually watch some tutorials